# SSIS - Script Task how to fetch get line number when error occurs

Tags: ssis

How to capture LINE NUMBER when any of your code fails in SSIS Script Task

Following code doesn't give line number of which error happened.

```
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        Dts.Events.FireError(1, ex.TargetSite.ToString(), ex.Message.ToString(), "", 0)
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure
```

Please advice

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Edmund, we could not get the line numbers. Try to use the ex.StackTrace to get more insight about the errors / exception. Try to use the following line in your Script task.

```
MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
Dts.Events.FireError(1, "Component Name", ex.StackTrace, "", 0)
Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just make sure you take all the `MessageBox.Show` calls **out** of your scripts **before** you deploy the packages. Having a package hang on the production servers because it's waiting for someone to click `OK` is ... embarrassing, to put it mildly.

Comment: @EdmundSchweppe - Any way to log the error to a folder specified by an SSIS variable, instead of using messagebox ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that line numbers in stack traces **are not available** to Script Tasks. I don't believe that Visual Studio Tools for Applications (VSTA), used by SSIS for Script Tasks and Components, can be set up to allow debug builds of the scripts themselves. Without the debug info, the .NET runtime can't determine what line of source code corresponds to the instruction in the compiled code where the error occurred.

Frankly, however, if you've got so much code in a particular Script Task that you **need** line numbers to navigate it, you have IMHO a much bigger issue. I'd suggest that you move that functionality into a custom task, or at least put the complex code into a separate .NET assembly that you can reference from your Script Task. Script Tasks are great for small bits of code, but as a full-bore development environment, VSTA stinks compared to the "real" Visual Studio.

Comment: An alternate approach I find helpful is to write my methods in a C# console project and then push the working logic into the script component. SSIS 2012 alleviates this by allowing debugging within components

Comment: I disagree that the amount of code is relevant to this shortcoming.  Debugging even a short script without knowledge of the location of the bug or the input data causing the fault is like attempting a ciphertext-only crypto attack, which is the worst-case-scenario.

Answer (score 1):

As you have identified, you can't get line numbers from a release build stack trace. But what about method calls? Perhaps you can break down long methods into multiple method calls that help describe the workflow of the longer method. When an error occurs, you'll have a shorter method to inspect.